# How do you translate "cuando llegue mañana, hoy ya se habrá ido para siempre"?

Tags: traducción

> Cuando llegue mañana, hoy ya se habrá ido para siempre.

About this sentence *cuando + subjuntivo*, *habrá (future)*:
How can you translate this and when do you use this kind of structure?

If you can give me more examples it would be a big help.

Comment: Thanks a lot all for the explanations. I read this in a book and now i get it . Big help. Gracias.

Comment: Please choose an answer as the best fit to you, to avoid leaving the question indefinitely open.

Answer (score 5):

***Cuando + subjuntivo*** expresses that you are talking about a thing that is to come. It is standard when you want to use **When** with a time in the future:

When tomorrow comes. -> *Cuando llegue el mañana.*

When she drinks this bottle, she will die. -> *Cuando ella beba de esta botella, morirá.*

We will address this when we reach the meeting. -> *Nos ocuparemos de eso cuando lleguemos a la reunión.*

In english you use "when something happens, something else will happen" and you put the future tense only in the main sentence, while in spanish we use subjuntive on the subordinate, which acts as a *Complemento Circunstancial de Tiempo*

*-Papi, ¿cuándo llegaremos? -Cuando lleguemos*

This split example shows the simplest case: ***Llegaremos cuando lleguemos.*** -> We will arrive when we arrive.

Answer (score 1):

The translation for:

```
Cuando llegue mañana, hoy ya se habrá ido para siempre.
```

Is:

```
 When tomorrow comes, today will be gone forever.
```

**En mi opinión.**

Esta frase se usa para hacer énfasis de que el tiempo no se detiene y en el futuro te podrás arrepentir de no haber hecho algo en el pasado.

Esta frase me recuerda un refrán muy popular en mi país Cuba

```
No dejes para mañana lo que puedas hacer hoy.
```

En este link puedes leer esa frase http://www.motivaciones.org/MOTIV004/ctosehoyvoyamarcarladiferencia.htm

---

**IMO**

This phrase is used to make emphasis on that the time doesn't stop, and you will regret not having done something before.

This phrase remember me a saying that is very popular in my country Cuba

```
Don't leave for tomorrow what can be done today.
```

You can read the examples here:  http://www.poweroffreedom.ca/quotable-quotes/

Answer (score 0):

There are two sentences:

1. Cuando mañana llegue "Simple present"
2. Hoy se habrá ido para siempre "Perfect future"

So the translation would be something like:

> When tomorrow comes, today will have gone forever.